# How to properly fit plotly graphs in RMarkdown html documents?

Tags: html, r, plotly, r-markdown

I am trying to include **plotly graphs** produced by `timetk functions` in **rmarkdown html notebook** but I am not sure why these plots shrink in width in the html document whereas they appear fine in rmardown source editor.

To adjust the plots I have changed the chunk options to:

`{r, out.width= "100%"}`

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, mmessage = FALSE, warning = FALSE,
                      fig.width=12)
```

When I generate the html document I have noticed couple of issues with plotly graphs not fitting properly (in width) in the html document

**1) Graph is not spread to 100 % of the width as the document chunks size**

`Left Side` of image is from rmarkdown source editor, `Right Side` is from html notebook

[image]

**2) the legend overlaps the graph.**

`Left Side` of image is from rmarkdown source editor (correct plot), `Right Side` is from html notebook (overlapping legend)

[image]

**How do I fix these issues ?**

Appreciate any help here!!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Even today this problem persists.

Comment: @AshwinMalshe No, I wasn't able to resolve it back then & never tried it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try disabling autosize and setting the width manually with `layout`.

```
x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
dd <- data.frame(x, random_y)

fig <- plot_ly(dd, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>% 
  layout(autosize = F, width = 900, height = 500)

fig
```